# Logitech GHUB Macros Not Working for G613 Keyboard

Tags: logitech-keyboard

***Macro for G1 Key: Ctrl+W*** 
[image]
[image]
I use this simple macro because, why else is a macro for? For something you use very often.

**What works:**

1. A macro to type an email. Works. "mymail@mail.com" works.
2. A macro to open a program. Works. G2 Opens C:\Windows\notepad.exe
   works.

**Not working:**

1. A macro to press two keys. Control(down) + W(down) + W(up) + Control(up). Fail.
2. A macro to press Control + W, once. Fail.
3. A macro to open a program (e.g. C:/.../myscript.bat). Fail.

**OS:details**

Windows 7 Ultimate, 16GB RAM, 2TB of storage.

**What I've done:**

1. Uninstalled GHUB. Deleted files suggested [here](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023192454-G-HUB-Install-Uninstall-Update-Troubleshooting).
2. Reinstalled GHUB as Admin (RClick on setup.exe Run As Admin)
3. Uninstalled Drivers. Reinstalled Drivers.
4. Set Default Profile to Persistent.

**Back Story:**

I've been in email after email with Logitech Tech Support for weeks. You know tech support, very cookie-cutter responses. Did you try to reboot? Did you reinstall? What's your OS? And finally they want a download of my logs. Um, you can't have a set of keys to my house even though you agree not to enter and steal, but thank you stranger that got a tech job somewhere in cyberspace.

Exhausting all suggestions within a couple weeks of correspondence with Logitech Support, they have finally offered a link for me to submit bug/glitch report to their development team, which is what I was assuming to begin with.

The keyboard boasts that Macros can be easily implemented with GHUB software as a default persistent setting for Desktop usage, but it fails. Obviously this software was debugged and tested via games installed on a system. But as a person not gaming, I bought the keyboard for it's wireless/mechanical and build in hotkeys for running macros/scripts and unfortunately doesn't work with current state of software. As a developer myself it's obvious this was overlooked as a basic function.

My keyboard:
[image]

**Note:** 
LGS is a depricated software, the download links on websites will default to the GHUB software, the software that replaces/supersedes LGS.

Comment: Does it work with ctrl + F4 to close a window? Some windows don't respond to ctrl + W.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I would only use Control + W, works with everything I do. I use this on my keyboard manually, I also use this with Autohotkey. I wouldn't ask if it didn't work otherwise. control + W will close a windows window, also a tab on Chrome. However Alt + F4 will close a program. I did try Control + F4 just now and it does not work. I have fully become aware that LGHUB's software does not work for this type of keybinding and Desktop functionality. It may work for games, but I'm not a gamer. The advertisements discuss "persistence" for "Desktop" but it's not accurate and is a fallacy.

Comment: Does it work if you use a "hotkey" macro instead of a "keystroke" macro? (Using the names from [Customize G-keys on the G613 gaming keyboard with Logitech Gaming Software](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360023265334).)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Are you familiar with GHUB software? You cannot use a "hotkey", at least not for my keyboard G613. There is a set of keys; decicated hotkey. Exactly what I am doing, G1 a dedicated hotkey. I will upload a link to the keyboard. G1 through G6 (I guess dedicated hotkeys). The link you provided is a software I tried, but works the same, and doesn't work the same also. The software (when installed together) is Warned as "old software" (or deprecated; as to don't use because it's old hat; old tech). Basically GHUB is the new software which supersedes.

Comment: Sadly, or perhaps fortunately, no; I was partly going on how SetPoint works, it's not as if they'd miss out functionality from a much earlier version /s. I ended up at the LGS page because I used Logitech's search. I guess you've already looked to see if there is some sort of text configuration file that could be editable to make it do what you want. The [G HUB manual](https://www.logitech.com/assets/65550/ghub.pdf) on page 20 seems to indicate that you can drag-n-drop commands onto the keys, but frustratingly the Windows commands list doesn't happen to be scrolled to show "Close window".

Comment: @AndrewMorton SetPoint worked very well. I even bought the same keyboard twice  because of the Fn (Blue function keys aka hotkeys).  I've exhausted all troubleshooting for GHUB software. Thanks for chiming in. It's a GHUB engineering issue; software development. One day, hopefully, they will address the problem. Yes, I've seen those commands you mentioned. I think the root of the problem is something out of my depth (e.g. a *.dll within Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEM**: *LGHUB software, two fold.*

1. Desktop Persistence: Is a false claim and Logitech GHUB(soft)->Macros don't use
   keyboard key sequences as expected.
2. System -> Launch Applications:
       Only launch *.exe files (an application is many things, not only an
       exe file!) -- mislabeled or bug not anticipated for techies that
       write "applications" under many types of files.

A HUGE workaround for such basic functionality.

**The expected result**: Close a window/tab via keyboard sequence "Control + W".

Workaround (too big for such a mundane task):

**1:** Create a script using AHK - SendInput and close script (use once).

[image: create scrips ahk]
[image: the script ahk]

**2:** The AHK software comes with a right-click command built into the software. Compile is as demo'd here, to create an "application" that GHUB understands (as it seemingly only recognizes *.exe files as application worthy).

[image: "r-click" and "compile script" - ahk file]
[image]

**3:** Assign "Launch Application" to G1 key for G613 keyboard.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem. Finally, I find out the logitech virtual keyboard and mouse driver are unsigned in device manager. 
You may follow the guide in the below link:

https://www.ngohq.com/driver-signature-enforcement-overrider.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not provide links to solutions that may not exist in the future.